# Adding Scrollbar to JTable cell with HTML rendering

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I want to add scroll bar to a cell in JTable which has HTML contents that needs to be rendered. Tried creating a custom cell renderer with following code snap. Scroll bar appears in the cell however I am unable to scroll.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent( JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column )
    {
          theLabel.setText((String)value);
         JScrollPane thePane = new JScrollPane(theLabel);
         return thePane;
    }
```

Any clues will be appreciated

Comment: Renderer is not real component. The componnet is used to draw only and can't process events. Try to create TableCellEditor

Comment: You need to use `TableCellEditor`for that.

Comment: I tried creating TableCellEditor also but the moment we click on scroll bars , raw HTML text is displayed. Any clues on this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments in this question, realized this problem needs a combination of TableCellEditor and TableCellRenderer. Could resolve this issue with both editor and renderer.